# Set cell content to normalized self

Tags: gnumeric

Not sure the title makes sense, but consider the following minimal spreadsheet :

```
    A  B
1   2  1
```

Is there a simple way to normalize `B1` to `A1`, i.e. set the content of `B1` to `B1/A1` (using the value in `B1`, not its reference) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Create a column C to do the calculation (C1/A1)
2. Write a macro